# Como remover linhas no PyQt

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3, pyqt-5

Preciso remover uma linha na tabela do Pyqt.
Na verdade ele carregar as linhas conforme o filtro. Mas na hora que vai abrir ele puxa os ID das linhas fora do filtro, como resolver isso?

Comment: O idioma do site é portugues, removi os trechos em ingles por notar que voce ja havia adicionado a traducao.